# Python WebDriver how to print whole page source (html)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using Python 2.7 with Selenium WebDriver.
My question is how to print whole page source with `print` method.
There is webdriver method `page_source` but it returns WebDriver and I don't know how to convert it to String or just print it in terminal

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[`.page_source`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) on a `webdriver` instance is what you need:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get('http://google.com')
>>> print(driver.page_source)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemscope=""><head><meta name="descri
...
:before,.vscl.vslru div.vspib{top:-4px}</style></body></html>
```

Comment: Thank You, this is exactly what I need!
That was my fault because I've done this in bad way `print driver.page_source` (driver.page_source wasn't in brackets)

Comment: page_source only seems to be what is visible, not the entire html source.