# Scraping data from complex website (hidden content)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am just starting with web scraping and unfortunately, I am facing a showstopper: I would like pull some financial data but it seems that the website is quite complex (dynamic content etc.).

[Data I would like pull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LfbR.png)

Website:
https://www.de.vanguard/web/cf/professionell/de/produktart/detailansicht/etf/9527/EQUITY/performance

So far, I've used Beautiful Soup to get this done. However, I cannot even find the table. Any ideas?

Comment: https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/  this might be what you are looking for.

Comment: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using `selenium` to launch an automated web browser. This loads the web page and it's associated dynamic content, as well as allow you the option to 'click' on certain web elements to load content that may be generated `on_click`. You can use this in tandem with `BeautifulSoup` by passing `driver.page_source` to `BeautifulSoup` and parsing through it that way.

This SO answer provides a basic example that would serve as a good starting point: [Python WebDriver how to print whole page source (html)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27411915/8146556)