# How to print all contents of webdriver in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

How to print all html/css tags/attributes of "browser"?

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

Comment: what do you mean by all html attributes ? Do you want all divs, span, iframe etc as your output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python WebDriver how to print whole page source (html)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411915/python-webdriver-how-to-print-whole-page-source-html)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(browser.getPageSource());
```

Comment: That is not python.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, for those who might find it useful in the future:

```
print(browser.page_source)
```

In general, to check/print/list ALL Methods and Attributes available to an Object use this:

```
print(dir(browser))
```