# How to get the result value of the URL shorten page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get automatically the result of the URL shorten. 
This is the page what I am using: [url shortener site](http://paylinx.pw/linx/)

This is the code I made (URLS list contains links):

```
driver.get("http://paylinx.pw/linx/")


for i in URLS:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="url"]').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="url"]').send_keys(i)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="invisibleCaptchaShort"]').click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

After this I get the `shortened url`. I would need a little help to get it somehow.

Comment: Have a look in `driver.page_source`, it's likely to be in there somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebDriverWait` to wait for short url result and get the value.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

with driver:
    driver.get("http://paylinx.pw/linx/")
    for url in URLS:
        driver.find_element_by_id("url").send_keys(url, Keys.ENTER)

        short_url = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".add-link-result .input-lg"))).get_attribute("value")
        print(short_url, url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use page.source, because it translate you page on need code, for chromedriver, some like lifehuck )) or you can use get_attribute('innerHTML') - you can access everything from the page.

[Python WebDriver how to print whole page source (html)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411915/python-webdriver-how-to-print-whole-page-source-html)

Answer (score 0):

To extract the result value of the URL shortener automatically you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  URLS = ['https://selenium.dev/downloads/','https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/']
  for i in URLS:
      driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
      driver.get("http://paylinx.pw/linx/")
      element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#url")))
      element.clear()
      element.send_keys(i)
      driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn-captcha#invisibleCaptchaShort").click()
      print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.input-group>input.form-control.input-lg"))).get_attribute("value"))
      driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  http://paylinx.pw/linx/Uksheqw8
  http://paylinx.pw/linx/s0DA44C
  ```